AWS Cloudformation Template - How to Import Values and Sub for ALB Target Group
I am creating an ALB via Cloudformation Template.  One of the resources being created is a target group that will use EC2 instance ID's that were exported during a previous job.  I need to import the values and sub the import name to reflect different environment deployments.  Running the cfn-lint tool, this is a correct template:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Creates an application load balancer.
Parameters:
  pSystem:
    Type: String
    Default: your-system-name
    Description: 'Name of the system. Default: your-system-name'
  pApp:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Name of the application solution'
  pEnvironment:
    Type: String
    Default: sbx
    Description: 'Name of the deployment tier. Default: sbx'
  pVpcId:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>

Resources:

  rLoadBalancerTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${pSystem}-${pApp}-${pEnvironment}-public-tg'
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 60
      HealthCheckPath: 'REDACTED'
      HealthCheckPort: 1234
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher: 
        HttpCode: 200-299
      Port: 1234
      Protocol: HTTP
      ProtocolVersion: HTTP1
      TargetGroupAttributes: 
        - Key: 'deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds'
          Value: 300
        - Key: 'stickiness.enabled'
          Value: false
        - Key: 'load_balancing.algorithm.type'
          Value: round_robin
        - Key: 'slow_start.duration_seconds'
          Value: 0
      TargetType: instance
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId: !Ref pVpcId
      Targets: 
        - Id: !ImportValue 
          Fn::Sub: '${pSystem}-${pApp}-01-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id'
        - Id: !ImportValue
          Fn::Sub: "${pSystem}-${pApp}-02-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id"
        - Id: !ImportValue
          Fn::Sub: "${pSystem}-${pApp}-03-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id"

However, I receive this error in Cloudformation when it attempts to deploy:
No export named found

Which I have verified that all of my expected exports match this naming convention and are present in their respective stacks.
Reviewing the Template in Cloudformation, the template is translated to:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Creates an application load balancer.
Parameters:
  pSystem:
    Type: String
    Default: your-system-name
    Description: 'Name of the system. Default: your-system-name'
  pApp:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Name of the application solution'
  pEnvironment:
    Type: String
    Default: sbx
    Description: 'Name of the deployment tier. Default: sbx'
  pVpcId:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>

Resources:

  rLoadBalancerTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${pSystem}-${pApp}-${pEnvironment}-public-tg
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 60
      HealthCheckPath: /rest/web/system-healthy
      HealthCheckPort: 30600
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200-299
      Port: 30600
      Protocol: HTTP
      ProtocolVersion: HTTP1
      TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
        Value: 300
      - Key: stickiness.enabled
        Value: false
      - Key: load_balancing.algorithm.type
        Value: round_robin
      - Key: slow_start.duration_seconds
        Value: 0
      TargetType: instance
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId:
        Ref: pVpcId
      Targets:
      - Id:
          Fn::ImportValue: ''
        Fn::Sub: ${pSystem}-${pApp}-01-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id
      - Id:
          Fn::ImportValue: ''
        Fn::Sub: ${pSystem}-${pApp}-02-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id
      - Id:
          Fn::ImportValue: ''
        Fn::Sub: ${pSystem}-${pApp}-03-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id

Which has an empty string ('') after the Fn::ImportValue, and doesn't appear to be reading the Sub command.
Any suggestions on how to import the EC2 instance ID's for the target group?

If you want to write raw yaml, consider avoiding thie exclamation mark style !.   It makes the yaml an out of spec, invalid pseudo-yaml that can not be read by most parsers  and redefines an already confused document spec to supply an unneeded equivalent to Fn::ImportValue: { "Fn::Sub":  "${blah}" }

I've had success with this format:
"Fn::ImportValue": !Sub ${pSystem}-${pApp}-01-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id

Also, documentation shows this format:
- Fn::ImportValue: 
  'Fn::Sub': '${pSystem}-${pApp}-01-${pEnvironment}-ec2-id'

So try adding single quotes around the Fn::Sub part.
Also, remember the rules of imports, such as same region, as listed in the same documentation.
